# how to extract value from *.cer file

Tags: openssl

I have a xyz.cer file and I am trying to extract the key out of it. I used command as `openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in <file>`

This gives error as x509: Unknown parameter.

can someone suggest whats missing.

Answer (score 2):

`openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.pem` outputs the public key.

If this doesn't work you may have a (weird) version of openssl compiled without x509 support.